# Ajax POST an object with javascript, but the value in backend is null, why?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, object

So on button click there is a function sendEmail(). Alert is working fine, I can see my datas there. But on backend I can't see anything, just everything is null.

```
   function sendEmail() {
        var datas = new Object();
        datas.mail = $('#contactDropdownList').val();
        datas.mailobject = $('#emailObject').val();
        datas.text = $('#emailText').val();enter code here
    
        alert(datas.mail + datas.mailobject + datas.text);
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Email/sendEmail",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ items: datas }),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //do something with data
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                //log or alert the error
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    
    }
```

C# code:

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Object { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

    }

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult sendEmail(MyClass items)
{
    return Json(new { data="Ok" });
}
```

items.Email, items.Object and items.Text are null.
And the return valu is null as well, because in javascript success: function (data) { console.log(data);
is empty string.

What can be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: you pass `{ items: datas }` instead of `datas`, also there is naming mismatch in `datas` object and `MyClass` properties. `mail` -> `Email`, `mailobject` -> `Object`

Comment: Also, pass the object directly as `data`. No need to to call stringify manually in most cases. Use the Network Tab to verify the expectations of the request sent.

Answer (score 1):

Model binder expects json content to match C# class. Your `datas` object should look like that

```
var datas = {
   email: $('#contactDropdownList').val(),
   object: $('#emailObject').val(),
   text: $('#emailText').val()
}
```

Since you wrapped your object (`{ items: datas }`), you may think it will be mapped to `sendEmail(MyClass items)`, but in reality `items` name does not matter, you can change variable name to any other name you like

Make sure you apply `[FromBody]` attribute to your parameter like that

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult sendEmail([FromBody]MyClass items)
```

Complete demo:

```
<script>
    
    function sendSmth() {
        var data = {
            Email: 'email',
            Object: 'object',
            Text: 'text'
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/home/index",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (datas) {
                console.log(datas)
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

And controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index([FromBody]MyClass obj)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @dejvide159357 just checked it, looks like `JSON.stringify` is required for ajax. I've updated my answer. also make sure you have `[FromBody]` attribute!

Comment: Use [HttpPost] with [FromBody] and "POST" on the frontend as shown in my example. [HttpGet] works because parameters are being put into query. You probably have typos

Answer (score 0):

As someone has noted, you have a mismatch between what you're sending to the controller and what the model the modelbinder is expecting. You can also vastly simply your AJAX code:

```js
function sendEmail() {
    var data = {
        Email: $('#contactDropdownList').val(),
        Object: $('#emailObject').val(),
        Text: $('#emailText').val()
    };
        
    $.post("/Email/sendEmail", data)
        .done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            //do something with response
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            //log or alert the error
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

You don't really need to specify the content type or data type - the $.post helper's defaults work just fine for what you've shown.